# Bubble Chart-Cannot read property 'length' of null at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:14)

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

```js
var popCanvas = document.getElementById("popChart");

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "Lato";
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 18;

var popData = {
  datasets: [{
    label: ['Deer Population'],
//data to plot bubble on chart
    data: [{
      x: 100,
      y: 0,
      r: 10
    }, {
      x: 60,
      y: 30,
      r: 20
    }, {
      x: 40,
      y: 60,
      r: 25
    }, {
      x: 80,
      y: 80,
      r: 50
    }, {
      x: 20,
      y: 30,
      r: 25
    }, {
      x: 0,
      y: 100,
      r: 5
    }],
//color properties for chart
    backgroundColor: "#9966FF",
    hoverBackgroundColor: "#000000",
    hoverBorderColor: "#9966FF",
    hoverBorderWidth: 5,
    hoverRadius: 5
  }]
};

var bubbleChart = new Chart(popCanvas, {
  type: 'bubble',
  data: popData
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="popChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Be more concrete what is the problem, cause I couldn't reproduce it: https://jsfiddle.net/1aujzssa/

Comment: I am new to jquery and just forget to add js code in **$(document).ready(function(){---}** thats why code get null for **var popCanvas = document.getElementById("popChart");** this line. After putting js code in ready function, it works. Thanks for comment  Tomas Eglinskas